# Why do leveraged and inverse leveraged WTI ETNs have this price relationship?

Tags: etf, price, commodities, leverage, trends

UWTI: 3x leveraged exposure to WTI

DWTI: 3x leveraged inverse exposure to WTI

The inverse relationship between these two symbols seems to trend toward the origin on a log-log plot (using log base 2).  I'm plotting only intervals of large movement, so not all days are shown.  Green intervals are ones where UWTI goes up.  Red intervals are ones where DWTI goes down.

**Question:** Why do green and red intervals have consistently different slopes that make the overall trend toward the origin (see blue arrow)?

[image: Relationship between UWTI and DWTI on log-log scale]

Note: Large movement was determined visually, from the bottom to the top (or vice versa) of intervals of significant price change.  The days that are not represented at all in this graph had no visually significant movement. Graph is based on daily close prices.